# Babelify sourceType error when used programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) to compile my source code from ES6 + JSX to plain Javascript.

My `gulpfile.js` looks like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var fs = require("fs")
var browserify = require("browserify")
var babelify = require("babelify")

gulp.task('es6',function(){
  return browserify({ debug: true })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
      extensions: ['.es6']
    }))
    .require("./src/es6/app.es6", { entry: true })
    .bundle()
    .on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error : " + err.message); })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./build/js/bundle.js"))
})
```

The first lines of my `app.es6` is:

```
"use strict"

import React from 'react'
import MenuBar from './menu'
```

When I run `$ gulp es6`, I get the following error:

```
Error : 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

However this does not happen when I use Browserify's cli:

```
$ browserify src/es6/app.es6 -t babelify -o build/js/bundle.js --extension=.es6
```

Any thoughts on how this problem can be resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `extensions:['.es6']` option needs to be added to browserify's configuration:

```
browserify({ debug: true, extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.es6'] })
```

The entire `gulpfile` should look like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var fs = require("fs")
var browserify = require("browserify")
var babelify = require("babelify")

gulp.task('es6',function(){
  var extensions = ['.js','.json','.es6'];
  return browserify({ debug: true, extensions:extensions })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
      extensions: extensions
    }))
    .require("./src/es6/app.es6", { entry: true })
    .bundle()
    .on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error : " + err.message); })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./build/js/bundle.js"))
})
```